# Interval for System.Timers.Timer not getting updated

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have created 2 timers and `dispatcherTimer.Interval` should be updated in the EventHandler for `dispatcherTimer2`. I have set a default value for the timer and on running the code I can see that it is getting updated but the EventHandler, `dispatcherTimer_Tick` is called after the default interval. I am not able to solve this problem.

Where am I going wrong and how do I fix this?

```
        System.Timers.Timer dispatcherTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        dispatcherTimer.Elapsed += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        System.Timers.Timer dispatcherTimer2 = new System.Timers.Timer();
        dispatcherTimer2.Elapsed += dispatcherTimer_Tick2;
        dispatcherTimer2.Interval = 10000;
        dispatcherTimer2.Start();
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = 120000;           
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoPlay.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            VideoPlay.Source = new Uri("http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test2_Talkinghead_mp4_480x320.mp4");
        }));
    } 

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(VideoDay + VideoHr.ToString()+videoMin.ToString());
        if(hourparameter==VideoHr && minparameter==videoMin && dayparameter==VideoDay)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            if (VideoHr == hour)
            {
                if (day == VideoDay)
                {
                    if (videoMin > min)
                    {
                        dispatcherTimer.Enabled = false;
                        dispatcherTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                        dispatcherTimer.Interval = (videoMin - min) * 60 * 1000;
                       System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(dispatcherTimer.Interval.ToString());

                        dispatcherTimer.Enabled = true;
                    }
```

EDIT: I have tried with DispatcherTimer again and also checked the times when the EventHandlers are called with some DateTime.Now functions. The problem is still there. if somebody wants I will put up the DispatcherTimer code. I didn't replace the `Timers.Timer`code in the edit because it would've changed the question. It's basically the same except for the syntax. The code is structured the same way.

EDIT: If I remove the default initialization for the timer interval it just calls the `EventHandler` continously.But at the same time the 2nd timer eventhandler is also getting called which in turns updates the Interval for the 1st timer. But it never gets used.

I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Note that If the interval is set after the Timer has started, the count is reset (see MSDN).  I suggest you remove the MessageBoxes, and instead log what's happening with a timestamp.  If you're still getting results you don't expect, post the code and the log.

Comment: Actually i took that into account. I'm only updating it after a check which ensures that it's not updated repeatedly. And the messageboxes tell me that it has been updated just the once. But still, the timer uses the default interval. 

I will log the events with a timestamp though and see what's going on. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Joe I don't know how to create Timestamps for `EventArgs` and I couldn't get anything off google. Could you give me something which I can use to log the events? Thanks!

Comment: System.Timers.Timer is an evil, evil class.  You have threading race bugs in this code that you cannot reason out.  And it is completely pointless when you have to call Invoke(), now it isn't better anymore than DispatcherTimer.  So simply use DispatcherTimer.  Expecting VideoHr == hour is also very wrong, that randomly won't work when the timer ticks a bit late.  Use DateTime instead.

Comment: I was actually using DispatcherTimer before moving to this. You can see the variable names are all DispatcherTimer because I didn't change the names when I changed the timer.  And I tried all the things which I've tried with this but am running into the same problem. And `VideoHr==hour` isn't the problem I think, because the Interval is getting updated there, the messagebox is showing up everytime. But that interval isn't getting used.

Answer (score 0):

System.Timers.Timer queues ticks in threadpool so you can't be sure that it stops when turn timer's Enabled = false.

You could try to set AutoReset = false at beginning. This makes sure that your timers are run only once but you have start them manually again in the tick code.

```
dispatcherTimer.AutoReset = false;
dispatcherTimer2.AutoReset = false;
```

Then you could just replace your timer code with this in dispatcherTimer_Tick2 to fire up timer again.

```
dispatcherTimer.Interval = (videoMin - min) * 60 * 1000;
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

And in the end of dispatcherTimer_Tick also

```
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

I'm not sure what kind behaviour you want but I hope that this helps you.